# Converting a Dictionary to a Tree in C# - fastest method?

Tags: c#, dictionary, tree

I have a *Dictionary<string,User>* containing every user in the company.  Each *User* has a *Manager*.   I want to be able to walk from a given *User* to everyone in their management chain.

The simplest way I can see to do this is to add a *Employees* property to *User* which will be a *List<User>* that points to all of the users they manage.

I'm then going to walk the dictionary, doing a lookup for each user (with ContainsKey) and then adding them to the appropriate manager.

Is there a faster way of doing this?  I feel like I'm scanning the table a lot (with a ContainsKey for each user's manager), but I can't see a way around that.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: It sounds like user is actually an `Employee`, and each employee has a `Manager` property, which itself derives from `Employee`. That way, you dont need to have a `List<Employee>`, you can simply traverse the graph of all managers for a given employee.

Comment: That takes you up the way, but means that I need to traverse the list of managers for every employee and see if I hit a given manager.  That's probably faster if I only want the one manager, but if I want to do repeated searches for different managers then I'd have to do a complete traversal for all employees with every search.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I've got right now:

```
var results = ActiveDirectory.GetUsers(filter);
var userList = results.ToDictionary(result => result.ID);

foreach (var result in results)
{
    if (userList.ContainsKey(result.Manager))
    {
        userList[result.Manager].Employees.Add(result);
    }
}
```

Which does seem pretty quick.  I just wonder if there's something faster I could be doing.

Comment: `Dictionary` is optimized for access by key. Don't think you'll get much better there. But you're accessing it twice, once with `userList.ContainsKey()` and once with `userList[]`. You could do it with one access with: `User manager; if (userList.TryGetValue(result.Manager, out manager) { manager.Employees.Add(result); }`

Comment: Btw. access by key is [O(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xfhwa508.aspx). So you're not "scanning the table" (O(n); `foreach (var keyValue in dictionary) { if (keyValue.Key == searchedKey) { return true; } } return false;`), you're directly accessing it by key (`dictionary.ContainsKey(searchedKey)`).